# Is it possible to protect images and documents on a website but still be able to access them from a password protected page?

Tags: php, html, password-protection

I run a website that has a page protected with a simple php password protection script (I have read that this isn't particularly secure but I can't use .htaccess with my host). The page needs to be protected because of the images and documents stored on it for the users. The php script works to protect the page but if you arn't logged in you can still access the images by just going straight to the domain (eg. http://example.com/images/example.jpg). Is there a way that I can prevent this from being possibel(prefrebaly without having to change the password protection methon). Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: How about creating the images through PHP scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have the private documents stored in a folder outside of the public folder. Then you simply need to set up a form which posts the password to another page which checks the pass, if it is a match load the image, else print an error.
The code would be something like this

```
if($_POST['PASS']=="strongpass"){
$img = 'root/blah/image.jpeg';
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
readfile($img);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting all the documents and images outside of your public folder on your host. Then access all of them through a PHP script that reads them from their safe location on the server and outputs them to the browser.

You can use functions like: http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php or http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php to read the file.

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents($secure_file_path);
?>
```

No one can access your documents from the browser unless they go through that script. Obviously the script that reads the document must be protected by some kind of authentication.